# Резкое увеличение времени записи в файл

Tags: c++, linux, c, алгоритм, golang

Я записываю бинарные данные в файл. Делаю это так: есть большие блоки данных (условно 5 — 10 Мбайт), они записываются в конец файла; в промежутках между этим, в разных частях файла происходит модификация маленьких блоков данных (16 байт).

До определённого размера файла, запись в файл ведётся быстро (относительно) — от 30 секунд до 1,5 минут. Начиная с того момента, когда файл весит ~ 5 Гбайт, время записи в файл резко возрастает до 7 минут и более. Причин этому я найти не могу.

Подскажите, в чём состоит парадокс?

Comment: Без кода и примеров данных этот вопрос не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: Считаем, что данные однородные. Данные -- русская вики.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/egorsteam/information-retrieval/src/1266a8673811d5a115d7e374db0c2765289e1b39/src/Scripts/MakerIndex/?at=default Запись происходит 
   fileIndex.AddIndex(&memoryIndex, tokeneizer.GetCountPages()) -- 49 строка. Есть предположение, что это файловая система чудить. Но это немного странно

Comment: Предположение правдоподобное, в какую файловую систему пишете?

Comment: @D-side файловая система -- ext4

Comment: Мне посоветовали использовать mmap, сейчас буду читать-курить

Comment: *mmap()* не спасёт от записей (с увеличением размера) в середину файла, если это специально не обрабатывается в драйвере файловой системы, что увеличивает фрагментацию данных на носителе.

Comment: если запись идет в конец и немного модифицируется в середине, а диск - обычный hdd размером 2 и  больше терабайт, то это похоже на [smr](https://habr.com/ru/company/seagate/blog/264553/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю дело в кеше ОС. Пока файл помещается в кеш - запись моментальная. Когда кеш кончается и начинается собственно запись на диск - скорость сразу падает.

Ваш тест из собственного ответа это же и показывает - если каждый раз открывать файл, писать чуть-чуть, закрывать - запись происходит в один и тот же участок диска, который уже в кеше и который между перезаписями скорее всего еще хранится в памяти и до диска дойдёт уже только последняя версия после всего цикла перезаписей.

Когда же вы пишите большой файл подряд - ОС кеширует сколько может, а потом начинает работать уже с диском (ну или писать в буфер, а старые буферы на диск скидывать) и скорость падает.

Answer (score 0):

Я постоянно файл держу открытым. Написал такой тестер

```
for j := 0; j < 6 * 2 * 2 * 2; j++ {
        file, _ := os.OpenFile("./data/1.dat", os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR, 0777)
        fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
        fmt.Println(j, float64(fileInfo.Size()) / (1024 * 1024))
        for i := 0; i < 128; i++ {
            b := [1024 * 1024]byte{}
            file.Write(b[:])
        }
        file.Close()
}
```

В этом варианте я постоянно открываю и закрываю файл. В таком случае запись в файл происходит очень быстро. Секунды. Если файл постоянно открытым, то получится такая байда:

```
file, _ := os.OpenFile("./data/1.dat", os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR, 0777)
for j := 0; j < 6 * 2 * 2 * 2; j++ {
        fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
        fmt.Println(j, float64(fileInfo.Size()) / (1024 * 1024))
        for i := 0; i < 128; i++ {
            b := [1024 * 1024]byte{}
            file.Write(b[:])
        }
}
```

Здесь запись происходит очень долго. Скорее всего проблема с кешированием